# Keyboard shortcuts for window placement not working

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, window-manager

I am trying to find a shortcut to tile windows right and left, but have trouble using both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>, 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> 
and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Num #</kbd> functions. 
I have tried to modify it by installing ccsm -> Window Management -> Grid and set "Put right" to <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>,  etc, and then logged off and on again, but nothing seems to work. 

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it?